# Turn 1 row into multiple rows in Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataset along the lines of:

| Account No | P01_Ind | P02_Ind | P03_Ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | Y | N |
| 2 | Y | N | Y |
| 3 | N | Y | N |

Is there a way of adding a transformation in Azure Data Flows so that each row would turn into 1 or more rows depending on these indicator columns? In this example, my dataset would become:

| Account No | Indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P01 |
| 1 | P02 |
| 2 | P01 |
| 2 | P03 |
| 3 | P02 |

I looked at Unpivot but I couldn't see how this would work with this data. Note that this transformed dataset would undergo further transforms and wouldn't be sinked after this step. Any tips gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ConditionalSplit` transformation then add `Indicator` column to each condition by 'DerivedColumn' transformation. Finally, use `Union` and `Select` transformation to meet your need.(You can sort output of `Select` transformation if you need.)

Steps:

1. create a dataset and its data like your provided.

[image]

2. use `ConditionalSplit` transformation to split data to different stream.

[image]

3. add `Indicator` column to each stream.

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. union three stream

[image]

5. use 'Select' transformation to delete P01_Ind,P02_Ind,P03_Ind column.
   [image]
6. sort output of `Select` transformation.
   [image]

Data preview of 'Sort':
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for such a comprehensive and well-illustrated answer. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as doing a unpivot which will get you the rows with 'Y'/'N' as another column and then filtering the rest out for values of 'N'.

You will get

```
 1 P01_Ind Y
 2 P02_Ind Y
 3 P03_Ind N
 .....
```

It is scalable next time you have 10 instead of 3 columns.

Comment: Hi
Are you able to provide any more detail on this please? Thanks

Comment: Type this in the DSL script editor in dataflow. It is self explanatory. Substitute movies with the input stream name
`
movies unpivot(
    output(
     Product_Name as string,
     Indicator as boolean
     ),
    ungroupBy(Account_No),
    lateral: true,
    ignoreNullPivots: true
    ) ~> unPivoted

unPivoted filter( Indicator ) ~> filteredProducts
`